Movie about a mother falling in love with a man who can't marry her so she got married to another, then the same thing happens to her daughter
I saw a long movie a few years ago and it was 6 CD's. It was colored, American with English language and the time period is between 2000 and 2006 (I guess).
It was about a woman falling in love with some guy and she got pregnant, but they couldn't get married and she married another man and they had some other children but the first child was from her first lover. She had a girl and some years later the girl became a friend to a priest and they fell in love and then she got pregnant from him. But they couldn't get marry because the priest wanted to be a pop and finally she marries another man just like her mother.
Unfortunately, I don't remember anything else because I was so young then and also I didn't know the actors.

It sounds somewhat like the mini-series called The Thornbirds.  I know that you said you watched it in early 2000's, but is that when it was released?  The Thornbirds was a mini-series from the 80's.

@user22792 thanks a lot. thats the exact thing i was looking for.

As per a comment by @user22792 this is The Thorn Birds a 1983 Miniseries

The story centers on their daughter, Meggie, and her love for the family's priest, Father Ralph de Bricassart. Meggie tries to forget Ralph by marrying dashing stockman Luke O'Neill, but she and Ralph are soon reunited, with tragic consequences for them both.
IMDB Synopsis



Set primarily on Drogheda, a fictional sheep station in the Australian outback named after Drogheda, Ireland, the story focuses on three generations of the Cleary family and spans the years from December 1920 to December 1962.
Wikipedia

As for the DVD release

The Thorn Birds was released on VHS in 1991 in the US and Canada; it was re-released on DVD in the US and Canada on February 3, 2004. 


There was also a 1996 miniseries , The Thorn Birds: The Missing Years actually taking place in the middle of the original Thorn Birds miniseries.

It tells the story of the 19 years that are unaccounted for between the birth of Dane and Ralph's return to Australia in the original 1983 ABC miniseries, The Thorn Birds.
Wikipedia

